# compare two datatables with multiple columns with a unique id

Tags: c#

I have written a program to compare two datatables with unique ids and create another datatable to insert certain columns which have the same id in common. I have demonstrated my requirement below.

These are the tables that needs to be compared:

[image]

[image]

And i need the output as below

[image]

but i receive an empty table as the result. I cannot understand where have i gone wrong. Could you please help me on this. I have provided my coding below.Please not that quantity and input are two datatables

```
DataTable result = new DataTable();
result.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("id"), new DataColumn("qty") });         


            foreach (DataRow row1 in input.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row2 in quantity.Rows)
                {
                    if (row1["id"].ToString() == row2["id"].ToString())
                    {
                        result.ImportRow(row2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.ImportRow(row1);
                    }
                }
            }

        return result;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a [Left Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) of 2 Data tables.

```
        DataTable dtinput = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtquantity = new DataTable();

        dtinput.Columns.Add("id",typeof(int));
        dtinput.Rows.Add("2");
        dtinput.Rows.Add("4");
        dtinput.Rows.Add("7");

        dtquantity.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        dtquantity.Columns.Add("qty", typeof(int));
        dtquantity.Rows.Add("1", "12");
        dtquantity.Rows.Add("2", "13");
        dtquantity.Rows.Add("3", "5");
        dtquantity.Rows.Add("4", "6");
        dtquantity.Rows.Add("7", null);

        var results = from table1 in dtinput.AsEnumerable()
                      join table2 in dtquantity.AsEnumerable()
                      on (int)table1["id"] equals (int)table2["id"]
                      into outer
                      from row in outer.DefaultIfEmpty<DataRow>()
                      select row;
        DataTable dt = results.CopyToDataTable();
```

This diagram should help you in future:

[image]

Comment: hi thanks alot. But how can i combine "var results" to a datatable? Please help

Comment: You can copy to datatable `DataTable dt = results.CopyToDataTable()`

Comment: thanks, but there is no option called "CopyToDataTable". what would be the reason?

Comment: Are you sure you have added the required namespaces? Also check if your framework supports this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @hanzi_ru -  i think i know where the mistake was please see my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var result = input.Rows.Where(x => quantity.Rows.Amy(y => x == y));
```

I hope this helps!